# Why does init_pair fail for half of the COLOR_PAIRS range?

Tags: c, ncurses

On my platform:

- OSX Mojave 10.14.2
- ncurses from Homebrew:

  ```
  $ brew info ncurses
  ncurses: stable 6.1 (bottled) [keg-only]
  ```

building via this makefile configuration:

```
pkgenv=PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/opt/ncurses/lib/pkgconfig pkg-config ncursesw

flags=-Wall -std=c17 -ggdb
cflags=$(flags) $(shell $(pkgenv) --cflags)
ldflags=$(flags) $(shell $(pkgenv) --libs)
```

This minimum reproducible example fails:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <ncursesw/ncurses.h>

int main() {
    assert(NULL != initscr());
    assert(has_colors());
    assert(can_change_color());

    assert(ERR != start_color());
    assert(COLOR_PAIRS == 0x10000);
    assert(COLORS == 256);
    assert(ERR != init_pair(1, 9, 10));
    assert(ERR != init_pair(0x7FFE, 9, 10));
    // OK up to here

    // Fails
    assert(ERR != init_pair(0x7FFF, 9, 10));

    endwin();
    puts("OK");
    return 0;
}
```

But why? What `COLOR_PAIRS` reports (65536) and what `init_pair` accepts (1-32766) seem to be two different things. For what it's worth, browsing through the header file,

```
#define NCURSES_PAIRS_T short
```

It's weird that they chose a signed quantity for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [standard type](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcurses/init_pair.html) for a color pair is a (signed) ***`short`***, which on most machines is 16-bits.  The reason is that it dates back to the 1980s, when space (and color availability) were more limited.

[ncurses 6.1](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/announce.html#h4-new-library) has extensions that allow 32-bit values (e.g., using [`init_extended_pair`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_color.3x.html)), which *brew*'s [formula](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/ncurses.rb) appears to permit, though no one's commented on that so far.

As noted in the [*Portability*](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_color.3x.html#h2-PORTABILITY) section of the `init_pair` manual page

> ***X/Open  Curses***  does  not  specify a limit for the number of colors and
>          color pairs which a terminal can support.  However, in its use of short
>          for  the  parameters,  it carries over ***SVr4***'s implementation detail for
>          the compiled terminfo database, which uses *signed 16-bit numbers*.  This
>          implementation  provides *extended versions* of those functions which use
>          short parameters, allowing applications to use larger color- and  pair-
>          numbers.

For your amusement, the screenshots [here](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses-slang.html#compare_picsmap) use the extended number feature of ncurses 6.1

Comment: Fair enough; that still doesn't explain why `COLOR_PAIRS` would report 65536.

Comment: That's because ncurses 6.1 can store/report the values, but the standard says ***init_pair*** uses a ***short*** for its parameter.  ncurses 6.1 provides alternate ways to use the bigger numbers.